# Function run across 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function to compute the number of days between two dates using a 360 day year (if only it was just a 365 days difference lol).

```
def day_count_30_360 (start_date, end_date):
    """Returns number of days between start_date and end_date, using Thirty/360 convention"""

    d1 = min(30, start_date.day)
    d2 = min(d1, end_date.day) if d1 == 30 else end_date.day

    return 360 * (end_date.year - start_date.year)\
           + 30 * (end_date.month - start_date.month)\
           + d2 - d1
```

I am currently running a for loop to run each value but this is terribly slow.

```
for col in range(len(df_start_dt.columns)):
    for row in range(len(df_start_dt.index)):
        df_out.iloc[row, col] = day_count_30_360(df_start_dt.iloc[row, col], df_end_dt.iloc[row, col])
```

Is there any way to run both dataframes through the same function without looping? Thanks!

Example of dataframe:

Created dummy df for testing:

```
df_start_dt = pd.DataFrame([[pd.datetime(2004,1,1),pd.datetime(2004,1,1),pd.datetime(2004,1,1)], [pd.datetime(2004,2,2),pd.datetime(2004,2,2),pd.datetime(2004,2,2)]])

df_end_dt = pd.DataFrame([[pd.datetime(2005,1,1),pd.datetime(2005,1,1),pd.datetime(2005,1,1)], [pd.datetime(2005,2,2),pd.datetime(2005,2,2),pd.datetime(2006,2,2)]])
```

Both dataframes have the same index, headers, dimensions

Comment: You need to use `.dt` to access the `datetime` attribute e.g. `dt.day` etc.. besides what you're doing won't work even with the syntax error correction You're comparing a series of datetimes against a scalar and using `if`, this will bork as it doesn't understand boolean arrays. Are you trying to iterate over each row?

Comment: You are sending a column at a time, right? So, when you use `iloc[:, i]`, won't you be passing only a single column? But you are trying to access different columns, other than the one you are iterating over, inside the function.

Comment: Yea, im passing in a column at a time. Am trying to achieve passing both dataframes through this function. For the same index, compute the day_count_diff between the two dataframes

Comment: When you do `df_start_dt.iloc[:, i]`, your dataframe will only contain the column present at index `i`. Hence, you won't be able to access other columns since it becomes `[n] rows x [1] column`

Comment: Yea, understand that. But i cant seem to find another way to pass 2 dataframes through this function to compute for the same index and header.

Comment: Can you post the structure of your dataframe?

Comment: Sure! I tried using a loop and it works but is terribly slow. Have updated my question with the new codes. Any way to optimize this?

Comment: Updated with dummy dataframes!

Comment: Okay, structure cleared the confusion. So, if I am right, you want to subtract one cell of a dataframe with the cell present at the same location of another dataframe?

Comment: yep, thats right, but it is a 360 day calendar thats i cant just take dfa-dfb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) for one `df` and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate:

```
df = pd.concat([df_start_dt, df_end_dt], keys=['a','b'])
df = df.groupby(level=1).agg(lambda x: day_count_30_360(x.iat[0], x.iat[-1]))
print (df)
     0    1    2
0  360  360  360
1  360  360  720
```

Another solution with changing function:

```
def day_count_30_360 (x):
    """Returns number of days between start_date and end_date, using Thirty/360 convention"""
    start_date = x.iat[0]
    end_date =  x.iat[-1]

    d1 = min(30, start_date.day)
    d2 = min(d1, end_date.day) if d1 == 30 else end_date.day

    return 360 * (end_date.year - start_date.year)\
           + 30 * (end_date.month - start_date.month)\
           + d2 - d1

df = pd.concat([df_start_dt, df_end_dt], keys=['a','b'])
df = df.groupby(level=1).agg(day_count_30_360)
print (df)
     0    1    2
0  360  360  360
1  360  360  720
```

Comment: im getting a dataframe which is formatted in datetime format like so 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000360. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: What are your input df_start_dt? `print (df.info())`

Comment: my df_start_dt and end dt are same as above in the question!

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 3 columns):
0    2 non-null datetime64[ns]
1    2 non-null datetime64[ns]
2    2 non-null datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](3)
memory usage: 128.0 bytes
None

Comment: Ok, I am going check it.

Comment: For me it working perfectly. I use `pandas 0.20.3`. What is your version of pandas? `print  pd.show_versions()`

Comment: Gosh, it was really a case of different version. Was using 0.19.1. also learned that pip install pandas is different from conda install pandas. Thanks alot again @jezrael

Comment: Hi @jezrael, sorry to bother you again but can i ask how come in your concatenation, you are doing x.iat[0], x.iat[-1] instead of x.iat[0], x.iat[1]? i am creating a new concatenation of 3 dfs and am using x.iat[0], x.iat[1],x.iat[2]. Is there a difference?

Comment: I think there is no difference between [-1] and [1]. Because -1 means last item and 1 second item. I use it becase only 2 dataframes, so last item is also second item. So your code is right.